# Numpy array from centerline object

Tags: python, lidar, numpy, concave-hull

I created a Centerline object from a shapely polygon, which is basically a multiline string which contains the starting and endpoint of the centerlines. How can I transform this multiline string into a [start_x start_y end_x end_y] 4-column n-row numpy array?

```
x_coords = cloud[:,0]
y_coords = cloud[:,1]
array_2d = np.column_stack([x_coords, y_coords])
c_hull = alphashape.alphashape(array_2d, alpha)
kozep_vonal = Centerline(c_hull)
```

Comment: Which python libraries do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centerline returns a centerline.geometry.Centerline which is a multilinestring. You have to iterate through the multilinestring and get the coordinates of the first and last point from the line parts.
Here is a simple code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from centerline.geometry import Centerline
import numpy as np
polygon = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 4], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
centerline = Centerline(polygon)
c_array = np.zeros((len(centerline),4), dtype=float)
for i, l in enumerate(centerline):
    ll = list(l.coords)
    c_array[i] = [ll[0][0], ll[0][1], ll[-1][0], ll[-1][1]]
```

c_array will be:

```
[[0.25 3.75 0.75 3.25]
 [3.75 3.75 3.25 3.25]
 [1.25 2.75 1.75 2.25]
 [0.75 3.25 1.25 2.75]
 [2.75 2.75 2.25 2.25]
 [3.25 3.25 2.75 2.75]
 [2.   2.   2.25 2.25]
 [2.   2.   1.75 2.25]
 [1.25 1.25 1.75 1.75]
 [2.   2.   1.75 1.75]
 [0.75 0.75 1.25 1.25]
 [0.25 0.25 0.75 0.75]
 [2.   2.   2.25 1.75]
 [2.75 1.25 3.25 0.75]
 [3.75 0.25 3.25 0.75]
 [2.25 1.75 2.75 1.25]]
```

p.s. it is funny to see some Hungarian words in your code :)